# Inline SSH command

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to do a simple inline style SSH command, for example:

```
ssh foo@bar.com { cd foo/bar && rm *.foobar }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Should you want to execute `cd foo/bar && rm *.foobar` on the remote machine, simply do

```
ssh foo@bar.com  'cd foo/bar && rm *.foobar'
```

and see `man ssh`...

```
ssh [-1246AaCfgkMNnqsTtVvXxY] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D
[bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
[-i identity_file] [-L   [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
[-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-R
[bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-w tunnel:tunnel
[user@]hostname [command]
```

The parts you want:

```
ssh [user@]hostname [command]
```

Comment: Worth noting that you can pipe STDIN and STDOUT using this method as well- just the other day I made a HD image of a remote machine using DD over ssh.

Answer (score 9):

style 1: `ssh user@host 'embedded command'`

style 2: `ssh user@host " $(cat cmd.txt) "` 
cmd.txt is file that contain your remote command which is locate at your local machine

Answer (score 7):

yes it is :

```
ssh foo@bar.com 'cd foo/bar && rm *.foobar '
```